# How to display numbers in colour in a matrix (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, colors

Currently I have a matrix, say something like:
`A=[1 2 3 4 5;
   4 7 3 2 2;
   4 5 5 9 1]`

What I want is to somehow display the final 'n' columns of this in a certain colour, where n can be 1,2,3,etc. So if n=1, I'd want to display the matrix as it is, but with the column `[5;2;1]` to be coloured red. Is it possible to do this in MATLAB? If so, how?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is using [`cprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093-cprintf-display-formatted-colored-text-in-the-command-window?focused=3880898&tab=function) and `for`:

```
certainColor = 'green';
rowLength = size(A,1);
columnLength = size(A,2);
for idx = 1 : rowLength
    for jdx = 1 : (columnLength - n)
        cprintf('text', '%d\t', A(idx,jdx))
    end
    for jdx = n : -1 : 1
        cprintf(certainColor, '%d\t', A(idx, columnLength - jdx + 1))
    end
    cprintf('text', '\n')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this does help to colour it. However the problem is it is displaying it as a string of numbers (a vector, essentially), rather than as the matrix, how can I fix this?

To be specific, it turns the matrix I used as an example above into the following:

`1 2 3 4 5 4 7 3 2 2 4 5 5 9 1`

(with the correct colours). On top of this, the double arrows (>>) appear at the end of this string rather than below it, and the arrows are coloured green.

Comment: I've added `\n` to get each row, in each line.

Comment: Sorry, but I seem to have noticed another issue with this code - it swaps the columns. So if I coloured the last 3 columns, the if the columns are originally 1,2,3,4,5, then after colouring, they become 1,2,5,4,3. I think this can be fixed by changing the 8th line to: `for jdx=n:-1:1`